# how to select max top 10 (n) rows with there size?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I already have the below query that gets the size of tables. However I am intersted only to get top 10 max size table with there size.

how to do that ?

```
select convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) AS pages,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) * (@@maxpagesize/1024) AS kbs
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name
```

searching for similar: `select top 10 max(datapages) from sysobjects`

edit:

Also now I have to get the size of indexes, adding sysindexes to the query is enough or should add another system table like syscoments ?

writing it such way is giving me top table name:

```
select top 10 convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) AS pages,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) * (@@maxpagesize/1024) AS kbs
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by table_name , kbs
```

this is throwing error

```
select top 10 data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) * (@@maxpagesize/1024) AS kbs ,
convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) AS pages
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by  kbs , table_name
```

Comment: Can't you just change the `order by` to `kbs`, and add `top` to the existing query?

Comment: @MichaelGardner ok I will try that now , by the way I need now to get the  size of the indexes too, adding sysindexes would be enough ?

Comment: btw writing it such way is throwing error top 10 data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) * (@@maxpagesize/1024) AS kbs

Comment: @MichaelGardner I have edit my question

Comment: @MichaelGardner still throwing error , please check my edit ( last query)

Comment: @MichaelGardner temp table ? ill try that. for now I am testing the size of indexes

Comment: Got my ASE issue sorted, and was able to test out, and get the query running - check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Query works on my ASE 16.0 system:

```
select top 10 convert(varchar(30),o.name) AS table_name,
row_count(db_id(), o.id) AS row_count,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) AS pages,
data_pages(db_id(), o.id, 0) * (@@maxpagesize/1024) AS kbs
from sysobjects o
where type = 'U'
order by kbs DESC, table_name ASC
```

Comment: oh ok you added desc , very nice , what about indexes , sysindexes not working with me.